# How to replace NaN values from a column based on a condition from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, conditional-statements, nan

I want to replace np.nan values in a column, based on a condition from another column. What is more, I want to replace the np.nan value with a string:

I already tried with np.where, but I get an error "Invalid syntax" and I really don't see where my syntax is wrong.

```
casualty_data["age_band_of_casualty"] = np.where(casualty_data["age_of_casualty"]>0 & casualty_data["age_of_casualty"]<=5, "0-5", continue)
```

```
                  age_of_casualty   age_band_of_casualty                    
Accident_Index                                  
2016010000005       23                    21-25     
2016010000006       38                    Nan   
2016010000008       24                    21-25 
2016010000016       58                    Nan   
2016010000018       28                    26-35
```

From this table I want to get the following output:

```
                  age_of_casualty   age_band_of_casualty                    
Accident_Index                                  
2016010000005       23                    21-25     
2016010000006       38                    36-45     
2016010000008       24                    21-25 
2016010000016       58                    56-65 
2016010000018       28                    26-35
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```py
casualty = casualty_data['age_of_casualty']
replacing_values = (casualty-2).map(str) + '-' + (casualty+2).map(str)
casualty_data["age_band_of_casualty"].fillna(replacing_values)
```

Comment: It can be more efficient by computing `replacing_values` only on the rows with missing values.

Answer (score 0):

I would have just added a comment, but due to a lack of reputation have to write it here. Try adding the parentheses in your expression:

```py
casualty_data["age_band_of_casualty"] = np.where((casualty_data["age_of_casualty"]>0) & (casualty_data["age_of_casualty"]<=5), "0-5", continue)
```

It should help.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives the same error. Invalid syntax.

Comment: `continue` is a Python keyword. It is unclear what it is used for here but that definitely causes problems.

Comment: I thought so too, because the arrow shows the end of the function, which means either missing ) or something with the word continue. :)